# How to add driver template to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: project, wdk

The title pretty much sums it up. I need a way to manually add a windows driver templates to the new project window. I tried reinstalling WDK but it told me it was up to date. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC566785.png

Answer (score 1):

For this you must perform below steps:

1) Install msvc 2012
2) Install WDK 8 (only wdk 8 has support for msvc), if you have wdk 7600 or above - uninstall it and after install new wdk. Don`t try 8.1 because it in pre release state.

After this you must get that you want.

Comment: i have VS2012 Ultimate and install WDK8.1 but my visual studio have not any template

Comment: These templates only come with VS2013.